# HTC One offline in Eclipse Android device chooser

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

In Android Device chooser, it shows **AVD name**: `N/A , Target: unknown , state: offline`.

Any idea? I'm using the latest Eclipse and ADT. HTC is running on android 4.3.

Comment: Have you tried to press "Reset adb" (yellow triangle with red exclamation mark) in Eclipse?

Comment: @Victor that worked thanks! A message on the phone asked for permission to allow debugging mode on my PC. That didn't happen with my S3 phone

Answer (score 0):

If the devices tab isn't showing, *Window > Show View > Other*, then select *Devices* from the list.

Go to the Devices tab, above the top right of the tab pane is a downward triangle button (with a *View Menu* tooltip), at the bottom of its menu is *Reset adb*.